# Constructing HTML by inserting attributes at specific positions

Tags: python

We are consuming an API that returns plain text and it returns the HTML attributes in a separate node. I am having a hard time inserting the HTML attributes at the correct positions. Looks like the source is using a JavaScript framework but I feel that this should be achieved using Python too. Here is the JSON response:

```json
{
    "job_id": 2756674196,
    "title": "Technical Recruiter (Software Engineering) - Fully Remote - 6 month Contract",
    "employment_status": "Contract",
    "description": {
        "text": "At Careem, we are driven by the purpose of simplifying the lives of people and building an awesome organization that inspires. Based in Dubai, we started our journey as a pioneer of the Middle East’s ride-hailing economy.\nToday, Careem is the region’s everyday Super App operational in 13 countries and over 100 cities. The SuperApp provides a host of daily services that people need to move around, to order things and to transfer money in one unified smartphone app. Our goal is to simplify people’s daily lives so that they can spend their precious time and mindshare on things that really matter and on realizing their potential.\nCareem became a wholly owned subsidiary of Uber Technologies, Inc. in January 2020. www.careem.com  About the role:We are looking for a Talent Acquisition Specialist who will meet the evolving hiring needs of a high growth company through sourcing, recruiting and hiring talent. In this role, you’ll be a critical member of the Software Engineering Squad, partnering with the Engineering teams and driving the recruiting process to identify the right fits for our sophisticated, growing technology team.\nIndividual Accountabilities:Stakeholder Management - Partner with the stakeholders to provide insights and expertise on sourcing for talent and suggest creative ways for addressing talent acquisition challengesCollaboration - Work closely with the HR business partners to understand the recruitment needs for the quarter/ yearCandidate Experience - Manage effective communication with candidates and set expectations throughout the process to provide for seamless experience.Execution - Enabling and educating hiring managers on the recruitment process and ensure that the experience for both candidates and hiring managers is seamless.\nKey responsibilities include:Develop and drive the tech recruiting strategy for the regionRoles to be hired range from Backend, Mobile, SRE, Engineering ManagersPartner with the business throughout the hiring process, from creating job descriptions, to ensuring established processes are followed to ensure a positive candidate experienceProactively headhunt, screen and shortlist top talentProvide Hiring Managers with regular updates and summaries of recruiting progress and activityWork with Hiring Managers to determine best fit candidates, co-ordinate interviews, obtain qualitative feedback and present/manage through to offer stage\nWhat we are looking for:At least 2 – 3 years in house experience, hiring specifically hiring for Engineering and ProductOverall 5 years plus experience, ideally with a mix of agency and in-houseSolid experience with an ATS (We use GreenHouse)Strong stakeholder management",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "start": 0,
                "length": 221,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 221,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 221,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 222,
                "length": 411,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 633,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 633,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 634,
                "length": 99,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 733,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 733,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 734,
                "length": 15,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 734,
                "length": 15,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 749,
                "length": 388,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1137,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1137,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1138,
                "length": 28,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1138,
                "length": 28,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1166,
                "length": 182,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1348,
                "length": 116,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1464,
                "length": 149,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1613,
                "length": 161,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1166,
                "length": 608,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List": {
                        "ordered": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1774,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1774,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1775,
                "length": 29,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1775,
                "length": 29,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1804,
                "length": 61,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1865,
                "length": 71,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1936,
                "length": 177,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2113,
                "length": 53,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2166,
                "length": 94,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2260,
                "length": 153,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 1804,
                "length": 609,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List": {
                        "ordered": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2413,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2413,
                "length": 1,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2414,
                "length": 24,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2414,
                "length": 24,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2438,
                "length": 96,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2534,
                "length": 74,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2608,
                "length": 48,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2656,
                "length": 29,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2438,
                "length": 247,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List": {
                        "ordered": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "start": 2685,
                "length": 0,
                "type": {
                    "com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "salary_insights": {
        "jobCompensationAvailable": false
    },
    "required_skills": [
        "Back-End Web Development",
        "Engineering",
        "Site Reliability Engineering",
        "Job Description Development",
        "Communication",
        "Applicant Tracking Systems",
        "Stakeholder Management",
        "Strategy",
        "Greenhouse",
        "Candidate Experience"
    ],
    "company_details": {
        "name": "Careem",
        "logo_url": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQECakFb5lj_aw/company-logo_400_400/0/1606036699836?e=1643241600&v=beta&t=BzDbCVAA7BgkE4HT64opVacPlDGUw7WBG8DsewrocoE",
        "profile_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/careem",
        "profile_id": "careem",
        "followers": 263634,
        "staff_count": 3554,
        "description": "At Careem, we are driven by the purpose of simplifying the lives of people and building an awesome organisation that inspires. Based in Dubai, we started our journey as a pioneer of the Middle East’s ride-hailing economy. Today, Careem is the region’s everyday Super App operational in 13 countries and over 100 cities. The Super App provides a host of daily services that people need to move around, to order things and to transfer money in one unified smartphone app. Our goal is to simplify people’s daily lives so that they can spend their precious time and mindshare on things that really matter and on realizing their potential. \n\nCareem is powered by awesome people. Our people are purpose-aligned and values-oriented. They are excited by the purpose of simplifying lives and building a lasting institution in the region, and live by our core values of shooting for the moon, being of service, and acting like owners. We thrive on diversity, and welcome people of all backgrounds who can subscribe to our purpose can live by our values, and have what it takes to build an institution that will inspire and last for decades and centuries to come. \n\nIn January 2020, Careem became a wholly-owned subsidiary of Uber Technologies, Inc. www.careem.com",
        "specialities": [
            "transportation",
            "technology",
            "logistics"
        ],
        "industries": [
            "Information Technology & Services"
        ]
    },
    "job_poster": {
        "first_name": "Ryan",
        "last_name": "Maguire"
    },
    "posted_on": "2021-10-17 17:42:29"
}
```

So far, I have tried inserting the elements into the string as well as I have tried splitting the string into a list and tried inserting the attributes as list items but without any luck. Looking forward to a solution.

Here is the expected HTML:

```html
<p>At Careem, we are driven by the purpose of simplifying the lives of people and building an awesome
    organization that inspires. Based in Dubai, we started our journey as a pioneer of the Middle East’s
    ride-hailing economy.</p>
<p><br>
</p>
<p>Today, Careem is the region’s everyday Super App operational in 13 countries and over 100 cities. The
    SuperApp provides a host of daily services that people need to move around, to order things and to
    transfer money in one unified smartphone app. Our goal is to simplify people’s daily lives so that they
    can spend their precious time and mindshare on things that really matter and on realizing their
    potential.</p>
<p><br>
</p>
<p>Careem became a wholly owned subsidiary of Uber Technologies, Inc. in January 2020. www.careem.com </p>
<p><strong> </strong></p>
<p><strong>About the role:</strong></p>
<p>We are looking for a Talent Acquisition Specialist who will meet the evolving hiring needs of a high
    growth company through sourcing, recruiting and hiring talent. In this role, you’ll be a critical member
    of the Software Engineering Squad, partnering with the Engineering teams and driving the recruiting
    process to identify the right fits for our sophisticated, growing technology team.</p>
<p><br>
</p>
<p><strong>Individual Accountabilities:</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>Stakeholder Management - Partner with the stakeholders to provide insights and expertise on sourcing
        for talent and suggest creative ways for addressing talent acquisition challenges</li>
    <li>Collaboration - Work closely with the HR business partners to understand the recruitment needs for
        the quarter/ year</li>
    <li>Candidate Experience - Manage effective communication with candidates and set expectations
        throughout the process to provide for seamless experience.</li>
    <li>Execution - Enabling and educating hiring managers on the recruitment process and ensure that the
        experience for both candidates and hiring managers is seamless.</li>
</ul>
<p><br>
</p>
<p><strong>Key responsibilities include:</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>Develop and drive the tech recruiting strategy for the region</li>
    <li>Roles to be hired range from Backend, Mobile, SRE, Engineering Managers</li>
    <li>Partner with the business throughout the hiring process, from creating job descriptions, to ensuring
        established processes are followed to ensure a positive candidate experience</li>
    <li>Proactively headhunt, screen and shortlist top talent</li>
    <li>Provide Hiring Managers with regular updates and summaries of recruiting progress and activity</li>
    <li>Work with Hiring Managers to determine best fit candidates, co-ordinate interviews, obtain
        qualitative feedback and present/manage through to offer stage</li>
</ul>
<p><br>
</p>
<p><strong>What we are looking for:</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>At least 2 – 3 years in house experience, hiring specifically hiring for Engineering and Product
    </li>
    <li>Overall 5 years plus experience, ideally with a mix of agency and in-house</li>
    <li>Solid experience with an ATS (We use GreenHouse)</li>
    <li>Strong stakeholder management</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could show a simpler example and the actual expected html output

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have added the snippet of the expected HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but I was also asking for a smaller JSON example. And now where is the code you're trying to use? Have you considered using a template library like Jinja2 or Mako to create proper HTML structures?

Comment: well I gues that's one way to describe a marked up document.  You're going to have to rebuild it as html yourself, either with manual string manipulation, or by building up a template dynamically and then populating it with the strings in between indexs.  Either should work and the boil down to the same thing: go through each attribute one after the other and build template/modify string to insert tags at the right points.

Comment: 'I've tried xyz but without any luck; looking forward to a solution' I guess what you mean is: this is what I tried, I don't know how to do it, could somebody point me the right way, but this reads initially to me as 'I tried something, looking forward to someone writing some code to do this as I couldn't'.  That's liable to get people's hackles up.  Including the code you actually tried (and showing how it fails) will go a long way to ameliorating that :)